# parsing an url for crawler

Tags: php, c++, url, urlparse

i am writting an small crawler that extract some 5 to 10 sites while getting the links i am getting some urls like this

```
../tets/index.html
```

if it is `/test/index.html` we can add with base url `http://www.example.com/test/index.html`

what can i do for this kind of urls.

Comment: In which language you are trying ?

Answer (score 1):

Url like these are [relative urls](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt) . ".." means "parent directory", whereas "." simply means "this directory", as in bash.
For instance, if you are looking at this page : http://www.someserver/test/foo/bar.html , and there is an url like this in it : "../baz/foobar.html", it will in fact point to http://www.someserver/test/baz/foobar.html I think. Just test.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) to get base directoy, remove the `..` using [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and append it there. Like this:

```
<?php
$url = "../tets/index.html";
$currentURL = "http://example.com/somedir/anotherdir";
echo dirname($currentURL).substr($url, 2);
?>
```

This outputs:

> http://example.com/somedir/tets/index.html

Comment: @greg0ire, the question is also tagged with `PHP`. Please take a look at the tags.

Comment: Oops, true! This is strange... upvoting bjskishore123's comment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this [URL Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) Wikipedia page.